# Почему Django не включает шаблон станицы?

Tags: django

Есть страницы `base.html` и  `login.html`, пытаюсь включить *login* в *base*, но безрезультатно. Прописываю,`{% extends 'base.html' %} { %block login% } { %endblock% }`.Подскажите, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В `base.html` в нужном месте вставляем `{% block login %} {%endblock%}`

В `login.html` все, что нужно добавить в `base.html` помещаем между
    `{% block login %}` и `{% endblock %}`

То есть, все, что вы имеете в нужном шаблоне должно быть обернуто между `{% block %}` с тем же названием, которое вы вставляете в базовый шаблон.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @SergeyABolkunov Лучший способ отблагодарить - проголосовать "за" и принять ответ участника [подробнее тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7124/252917)